# Basic circular permutation doubt.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can 3 men and 3 ladies be seated at around table such that no two men are seated together?

Here first we arrange the women in 2! ways.

Now in the remaining 3 positions we arrange the men in 3! ways.

Now here why is it 3! and not (3-1)! = 2! for men as it's circular permutation?

Comment: It's like benzene chlorination. You get only one arrangement MLMLML cyclically permuted to two (even and odd) places.

Comment: Do "basic" and "circular" refer to "permutation" or to "doubt"? I've never heard of basic permutations or circular doubts, though.

Comment: By basic, I meant it's a basic (or very easy) question :P. Not any kind of permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that while placing the ladies, we use $(3-1)!$ because one wlady is used to create a reference point for the circle, say by placing the "head lady" at the 12 o'clock position.

Afterwards, it is not required for the men because each lady is distinct, and where a man sits in relation to a particular lady matters.